# Not enough input arguments for CDF

Tags: matlab, distribution, cell-array

I am trying to plot a CDF for my data, but I get the following error message:

> Error using cdf (line 69) Not enough input arguments

My code:

```
 data =cell(1,5);
 for j=1:length(container)-7
        data{j} = some_values;
 cdfplot(data)
```

So data is a `1x5 cell` while inside of it, the values are the following
`1x14600double`, `1x260double`, `1x2222double`, `1x3000double`, `1x72double`

I am expecting a separate line for each of the double arrays i.e. my cdf figure to have 5 lines. 
But, the error message confuses me, since I definitely have passed data. Any ideas?

Edited: ok, I have misswritten instead of cdfplot(), I had cdf()... the problem stays the same

Comment: No real clue what you are trying to do, is it possible that you mixed up 'cdf' and 'cdfplot'?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. Random data: `A = {rand(1,14600) rand(1,260) rand(1,2222) rand(1,3000) rand(1,72)};` Bookkeeping: `szA = size(A);` Testing [`cdfplot`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/cdfplot.html):  `for k = 1:szA(2), subplot(5,1,k),  cdfplot(A{k}), end` works fine in MATLAB R2018b.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was the lack of knowledge on how cells and figures work.

```
figure;
hold on;
cellfun(@cdfplot,data);
```

This code did the job :)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the [OP's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57390041/8239061) using [`cellfun`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html), you can also solve this by **adjusting how you [access the cell array](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/access-data-in-a-cell-array.html)**.

**Key Idea:  Access `A` with `A{}` versus `A()`**

```
% MATLAB R2018b
% Sample data
A = {rand(1,14600) rand(1,260) rand(1,2222) rand(1,3000) rand(1,72)};
```

Notice that `A(1)` returns

> ans = 1×1 cell array {1×14600 double}

while `A{1}` returns the full 1x14600 double array (extracts it completely from the cell array).

```
% Example usage
szA = size(A);
for k = 1:szA(2)
    subplot(5,1,k)
    cdfplot(A{k})
end
```

From this example you can see [`cdfplot`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/cdfplot.html) works fine.

Comment: nice idea, that could also be implemented, and would make other adjustments easier